# Selenium Webdriver Python Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070012

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My Selenium Python Selenium Webdriver scripts run but sometimes they do not, it is intermittent.
I get the error: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070012 ('There are no more files.') for URL 'http://localhost:50540/'

```
    Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore 501\TestCases\VariablesPage_TestCase.py", line 35, in setUp
    self.driver = webdriver.Ie(Globals.IEdriver_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py", line 55, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 136, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 196, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070012 ('There are no more files.') for URL 'http://localhost:50540/'
```

How can i overcome this intermittent issue?
I have to click run about 5 times then the test case will eventually run

This is my Python Webdriver code which launches the browser from one of my test cases:

```
def setUp(self):

    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER["unexpectedAlertBehaviour"] = "accept"
    self.driver = webdriver.Ie(Globals.IEdriver_path)
    self.driver.get(Globals.URL_justin_pc)
    self.login_page = login.LoginPage(self.driver)
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(100)
```

The internet security options for all the zones, the checkbox is unchecked for Enable protected mode.  The level is set to Medium for all zones.